# How to make `boost::stacktrace` formattable with `fmt::format`

Tags: c++, boost, stack-trace, c++20, fmt

I'm struggling to get boost's stack trace library to interoperate with fmt, the trouble seems to be that I can't quite specialize a boost::stacktrace::basic_stacktrace. Anybody know what the underlying issue is?

```
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <boost/stacktrace.hpp>

using BoostTraceStackFrame = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(boost::stacktrace::stacktrace().as_vector().front())>;
template <> struct fmt::formatter<BoostTraceStackFrame> : formatter<string_view>
{
    template <typename FORMAT_CONTEXT> auto format(const BoostTraceStackFrame &rhs, FORMAT_CONTEXT &ctx)
    {
        return fmt::format(ctx.out(), "{}:{}\n", rhs.source_file(), rhs.source_line());
    }
};

using BoostTraceType = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(boost::stacktrace::stacktrace())>;
template <> struct fmt::formatter<BoostTraceType> : formatter<string_view>
{
    //possibly BoostTraceType = boost::stacktrace::basic_stacktrace ?
    template <typename FORMAT_CONTEXT> auto format(const BoostTraceType &rhs, FORMAT_CONTEXT &ctx)
    {
        return fmt::format(ctx.out(), "{}", fmt::join(rhs.as_vector(), "\n"));
    }
};

int main()
{
 auto trace = boost::stacktrace::stacktrace();
 fmt::print("Foo trace {}",trace);
}
```

[On godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/xoMvKMsjW)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just three small things:

1. Missing/wrong headers. You need to include `fmt/ranges.h` in order to support formatting ranges.
2. Wrong overload. The function for formatting into an iterator is `fmt::format_to`, not `fmt::format`.
3. These:

```cpp
using BoostTraceStackFrame = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(boost::stacktrace::stacktrace().as_vector().front())>;
using BoostTraceType = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(boost::stacktrace::stacktrace())>;
```

are fairly long-winded ways of writing:

```cpp
using BoostTraceStackFrame = boost::stacktrace::frame;
using BoostTraceType = boost::stacktrace::stacktrace;
```

And in particular, the problem was that the way you wrote the first one it was `boost::stacktrace::frame const` when it needed to not be `const`.

Comment: Cool, the `boost::stacktrace::frame const` got me, the rest were just some lame obfuscation. I'll follow up with the final version for reference. Thanks.